# How to use ( ) [ ] braces to allow as special characters in password regular Expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using the following regular expression for a password field in my project:

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[~!@#$%^&*)(_+-:[}="`])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$/
```

My requirement is to allow at least
1 Upper case
1 Lower case
1 Number
1 Special character

It should allow `~!@#$%^&*)(_+-:[}=" special characters. If I enter other characters it should not allow those.

But it is allowing other characters like `|\` etc.

I don't have much knowledge on regular expressions. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is placement of an unescaped `-` just after `+` in your character class which is in the middle and acting like a range between `+` i.e. `0x2b` and `:` i.e. `0x3a`. All the characters in this range are allowed due to this.

You can move `-` to end of character class or at the start like this:

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[~!@#$%^&*)(_+:[}="`-])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[~!@#$%^&*)(+:[}="`\w-]{8,}$/
```

**Also important** is to change DOT (any character) in the end to allowed set of characters as I've shown above.
[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/a4N8w9/2)

Comment: I again tried your solution with `Gt%:_=yh|\^5%3f` it is allowing `|\ <>` etc. Please guide me. I will accept your answer for sure.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the regex-specific characters ($,&,^,*,+,?,/,|,),(,],[,},{):

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\)\(\_\+\-\:\[\}\=\"\`])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$
```

I usually just escape all punctuation to be safe, but there is no need to escape #, =, :,

Comment: Inside a set, only `]`, `-`, `^` that need escaping!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir It depends on your Regex interpreter.  As I don't know what language is affected, I assumed it's either `Javascript`, `Perl` or `BASH`, in which case the way they treat certain characters differs.  My solution handles all cases for all languages.

Comment: He tagged the question [tag:javascript]!

Comment: But he also tagged "regex", and someone looking for a "regex" solution might land on this page.  Also, my answer isn't invalid in javascript...

Comment: That is awesome. Iam working in javascript. It worked fine for me. If there are any further modifications please edit the answer. It will help me more.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Yesterday, I was using RegularExpressions in Python3 (library **re**), and it kept crashing because I was looking for the string `<$$= .+ $$>` and no results were found because the string didn't end with `<` (as $ is the end-of-string character)

Comment: **First:** I said characters inside a set (`[]`). **Second:** I said in javascript not in other languages!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I guess that's up to you.  I prefer to use a syntax that is valid Regex no matter what language, but you can do what you want.

Comment: @SsJVasto I tried your solution with `Gt%:_=yh|\^5%3f` it is allowing `|\ <>` etc. Please guide me.

Comment: @IsettyRavitejakumar To specify what you want or don't, you simply use [], and ^ specifies what you don't want.

So if you want `anything except |\< and >` you'd use `^[^\|\\\<\>]+$`: `^` means **start of string**, [a] means **I want a**, [^b] means **I don't want b**, [a^b] means **I want a, but not b**.

you can see that `Gt` (I'm guessing Greater than), `|` and `\ ` are **before** your `^`, therefore, they're in the "allowed" list.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you don't want to allow just put them in square brackets([]) with hat sign(^)

example :

```
[^|][^/]
```

This will not allow these characters.

Try this :

```
Gt%:_=yh^|\5%3f
```