# How to make input password require at least one special character (bracket included)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was wondering how to add in the special character part with brackets like {} [] () and other stuff like " ' - to the unique character I tried below, but for some reason when I add in another of those characters it stops working.

```
<-- works but does not have any brackets or quotes for special character-->
<form acton = "#">      
    <input type="password" id="newPass" required
      pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[!@#$%^&*+`~=?\|<>/]).{8,}"

    <button>submit</button>

</form>
```

The part above works but does not have quotes or more special character

Code below has bracket but does not work

```
<-- does not work (if you do not enter special character user will be able to submit but it does not have any brackets -->

<form acton = "#">      
    <input type="password" id="newPass" required
      pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[~`!@#$%^&*()-_=+[]{};:'.,"\|/?><]).{8,}"

    <button>submit</button>

</form>
```

also this did not work (from an answer)

```
<form acton = "#">      
    <input type="password" id="pass" required
      pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[~`!@#$%\^&*()\-_=+\[\]{};:\'.,\"\\|/?\>\<]).{4,}">

    <button>submit</button>

</form>
```

I am looking for an answer that makes the bottom part (the one with brackets and all of those special character I included) works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since it is regex, all of the characters inside `[.....]` are allowed, so you should add brackets to there. You can do this with the usage of escape character (because brackets has a role in regex). So just add `\]` and `\[` to the characters allowed inside `[.....]`.

try:

```
<input type="password" name="pw" pattern="(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-\]\[])"
```

By the way.. I would recommend working with regex cheat sheet, it will help you a lot in validation tasks.

**As for your EDIT:**

The `"` and `'` needed to be escaped. While `\"` `\'` won't work you can use `\x27` and `\x22` instead, these are the hexadecimal representation of `"` and `'` in the ascii table.

try:

```
<form acton = "#">      
        <input type="password" id="pass"  required pattern = "(?=.*\d)(?=.* 
     [a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[~`!@#$%\^&*()\-_=+[\]{};:\x27.,\x22\\|/?><]).{4,}">

        <button>submit</button>

</form>
```

Comment: thanks is there a way to do the restriction without regex? I did not know another way so my my password is just a regex restriction for alphabet lower and upper number and now special characters

Comment: @dragonn When you are using `pattern`, you must use regex. If you want to avoid using regex, you can write your own validation function that listens to the input, go over each character and validate it. But it is less recommended. Regex are great for things like that.

Comment: if possible can you provide the code for all the character I wanted (check edit)

Comment: pro-tip: you don't need to escape the open-bracket `[` within a character class (but you **do** need to escape the close-bracket) — this is legal and works: `[a-z[\]0-9]`

Comment: @dragonn hey :) you will need to escape  `"` `'` as well if you want to include them. so add `\"` and `\'` to the list of characters inside `[....]`

Comment: np @SomoKRoceS -- similarly, `^` negates a character class but doesn't need to be escaped if it's not in the first position, compare matches for `[^a-z0-9]` vs. `[\^a-z0-9]` vs. `[a-z^0-9]` (first one is _do not match_ a-z0-9, the other two are equivalent)

Comment: thanks I tired it on chrome however it did not work and I see the characters <]).{4,}"> beside the input box

Comment: same issue on visual studio code it shows that the " inside the pattern is interfering with the pattern so after the " in the pattern everything outside the quote is ignore and is beside the input tag. I see input tag follow by \<]).{4,}"> submit also I remove the quote to see if that was the issue but once the quote was remove I tried it without special charater. It went through wentout saying you need to enter special charater

Comment: @dragonn yes :) fixed in the answer.

Comment: thanks it works. Can you explain what the x22 adn x27 are? nvm got it quotes haha stackoverflow doesnt allow bounty to be given until 24 hours pass :)

Comment: @dragonn of course.. these are the hexadecimal representation of `"` and `'` in the ascii table. you need to escape those characters (`\` will not work in this case)

Answer (score 1):

You should escape regex (e.g. `\]`) characters if they need to be matched during pattern search. Also, refer to the existing answer:

[Braces and brackets in passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42353753/how-to-use-braces-to-allow-as-special-characters-in-password-regular-exp)

**The following works for me, hopefully it should work at your end:
(I merely added escaped characters)**

```
   <input type="password" id="newPass" required
      pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[!@#$%^&*+`~'=?\|\]\[\(\)\-<>/]).{8,}">
```

Comment: tried but didn't work can you provide code for my example? I might have a typo that I did not see when I tried it

Comment: @dragonn Check if above suits your requirement. You may add more escaped regex characters within the scope of  square braces.

Comment: thanks but I wanted al the characters I mention someone else did it though. Thanks for the effort though

Comment: Yes I noticed lately, no problem on that, glad to have an optimal solution in place for everyone in the community

Answer (score 0):

You're actually very close. The biggest mistakes are:

You should `escape` some of the special characters inside the `character group` and you should have `hyphen as the last character` (otherwise it's a range).

Here is the RegExp you request:

```
<input type="password" id="pass"  required pattern = "(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[~`!@#$%^&amp;*()_=+\[\]{};:&apos;.,&quot;\\|\/?&gt;&lt;-]).{4,}">
```

**Update**: I forgot to html encode the pattern for use directly in html. Now it should work.

Comment: thanks tried it on chrome. Did not work I saw input but followed by <-]).{4,}"> then submit tag

Comment: and yes it was just a formatting error I am putting it on a single line